# How to let Firebase insert a record only when a Stripe payment succeeds?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I am writing a Web App where users can pay via credit card and book a room.
Showing Firebase configs in source code hasn't been a problem since Firebase uses user based security - a user can only write what he/she is allowed to write. However, when it comes to payment, I doubt if users may add bookings using the configs without going through payment process from the front end.

How may I ensure that when a booking record is inserted, there is something like a valid payment token?  Is this possible with my current choice of tools? (Firebase and Stripe)

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

Comment: Wow, I haven't checked the function-samples...  Thanks @RenaudT. !  Please submit as an answer ;) By the way, why is Google Auth needed? Due to `firebase-admin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe.

In this sample, the triggers are user creation (see below) or user deletion, but you could have another model.

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {....
```